# How do I save Json output to a SQLite database in c#?

Tags: c#, json, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to make an app in xamarin forms that gets information from bittrex then puts it into a model and then saves it to the local SQLite database.

Here is my code for saving things to the database:

```
    public class CoinsDatabase
{
    readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection database;

    public CoinsDatabase(string dbPath)
    {
        database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
        database.CreateTableAsync<Coins>().Wait();
    }

    public Task<List<Coins>> GetCoinsAsync()
    {
        return database.Table<Coins>().ToListAsync();
    }

    public Task<Coins> GetCoinsAsync(int id)
    {
        return database.Table<Coins>().Where(i => i.CoinID == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    public Task<int> SaveCoinAsync(Coins coin)
    {
        if(coin.CoinID == 0){
            return database.InsertAsync(coin);
        } else {
            return database.UpdateAsync(coin);
        }
    }

    public Task<int> DeleteCoinAsync(Coins coin)
    {
        return database.DeleteAsync(coin);
    }
```

Here is my code for getting the Json information and processing it:

```
async void Save_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CoinNameEntry.Text != null){
            var uri = new Uri("https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=btc-" + CoinNameEntry.Text.ToLower());

            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Coins coins = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Coin>(content);
                var coinItem = (Coins)coins["result"].ToObject<Coins>();
                await App.Database.SaveCoinAsync(coinItem);
                await Navigation.PopAsync();
            } else {
                await DisplayAlert("Alert", "An error occured getting the coininformation of " + CoinNameEntry.Text.ToUpper(), "OK");
            }

        } else {
            await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Please select a Coin first", "OK");
        }
    }
```

And this is my Coins model:

```
    public class Coins
{
    public List<Coin> coins { get; set; }
}
public class Coin
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int CoinID { get; set; }
    public string CoinName { get; set; }
    public bool Notification { get; set; }
    public string MarketName { get; set; }
    public double High { get; set; }
    public double Low { get; set; }
    public double Volume { get; set; }
    public double Last { get; set; }
    public double BaseVolume { get; set; }
    public bool TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public double Bid { get; set; }
    public double Ask { get; set; }
    public int OpenBuyOrders { get; set; }
    public int OpenSellOrders { get; set; }
    public double PrevDay { get; set; }
    public string Created { get; set; }

}
```

I have been trying to get this working for a week now and I was wondering if someone knows what i do wrong or if someone has tips on how to fix this problem.

*Please keep in mind that im a beginner with xamarin and C# :)*

Comment: Sadly for us you need to tell us the symptoms or errors..

Comment: You need to call "database.SaveChangesAsync()"; after all CRUD operations (Insert, Update, Delete)

Comment: What is the result of setting the variable `coinItem`? The `result` property of the json is an array, not a single object so I would guess that assignment would fail or result in null.

Comment: We can't help when we don't know the issue you're having

Comment: the issue is that I can't get output at coinItem also im getting error: cannot implicitly convert model.coin to model.coins and cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Coins' @InitLipton

Comment: the errors are for the Coins coins = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Coin>(content);
                var coinItem = (Coins)coins["result"].ToObject<Coins>(); piece

Comment: First off, you're telling the JSON converter to parse a Coin, but then try to assign the result to an object of type Coins. You will have to change one or the other, depending on what the json string is. After that it looks like you're trying to retrieve a single coin, but in all honesty I'm scratching my head as to how you're trying to identify the one you want. Could you clarify?

Comment: Hi @FraukeNonnenmacher Thanks for your answer, I want the information of xvg which gives me this Json output: {"success":true,"message":"","result":[{"MarketName":"BTC-XVG","High":0.00000096,"Low":0.00000090,"Volume":343159526.27353944,"Last":0.00000093,"BaseVolume":319.56795724,"TimeStamp":"2017-11-14T11:49:58.923","Bid":0.00000093,"Ask":0.00000094,"OpenBuyOrders":2770,"OpenSellOrders":19090,"PrevDay":0.00000095,"Created":"2016-02-17T22:42:03.61"}]}

Comment: I wrote a nuget package that could help, either look at the source or install and see if it right for you https://github.com/jacktux/Xamarin-CacheUtils

Answer (score 2):

OK, try this: First, add a `JsonProperty` to your coins class to map the result to the correct property:

```
public class Coins
{
    [JsonProperty("result")]
    public List<Coin> coins { get; set; }
}
```

Then replace the following two lines in your code:

```
Coins coins = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Coin>(content);
var coinItem = (Coins)coins["result"].ToObject<Coins>();
```

with

```
Coins coins = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Coins>(content);
var coinItem = coins.coins[0];
```

Please note that this will give you the first of the coins in the list - change the index or use LINQ if you want to retrieve a coin from somewhere else in the list.

I also very much suspect that your SQLite code won't do what you want. Currently all your methods act on a Coins object rather than a Coin object. Try changing the methods to

```
readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection database;

public CoinsDatabase(string dbPath)
{
    database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
    database.CreateTableAsync<Coin>().Wait();
}

public Task<List<Coin>> GetCoinsAsync()
{
    return database.Table<Coin>().ToListAsync();
}

public Task<Coin> GetCoinsAsync(int id)
{
    return database.Table<Coin>().Where(i => i.CoinID == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}

public Task<int> SaveCoinAsync(Coin coin)
{
    if(coin.CoinID == 0){
        return database.InsertAsync(coin);
    } else {
        return database.UpdateAsync(coin);
    }
}

public Task<int> DeleteCoinAsync(Coin coin)
{
    return database.DeleteAsync(coin);
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot you helped me, the only problem that i am having now is that i was binding context to a coin to delete it and that does not work anymore now. code : https://pastebin.com/HD4tPJYb on line 18 i gives me an error with coinItem (cannot convert from model.coins to model.coin)

Comment: I got another issue when running the app now: when i add a new coin it does not get saved. when i add a new coin the form is empty (how it supposed to be) then I type in for example xvg and save it, but then a new item appears in my list with coins but when i tap on the item to get the saved information it's all empty.

Comment: @Kevin you really, really, really need to learn how C# classes work. I've had a quick look at your code and you're still using Coins where you should be using Coin and vice versa. That is going to cause problems throughout your code and, unfortunately, is way beyond your original question. As a beginner I suggest you don't use var - that will highlight a lot of the problems you're having.

Comment: @Kevin the code in pastebin isn't completely sufficient for me to diagnose the problem. If, after checking it for the things I suggested above you still run into trouble, the best thing would be for you to open another question. Tag me in a comment and I'll try to help :)

Comment: @Kevin if you want to learn more about C# and Xamarin (you're really jumping in at the deep end here), Microsoft Virtual Academy has some great, free courses: https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/c-fundamentals-for-absolute-beginners-16169 and https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/xamarin-for-absolute-beginners-16182?l=fPHWqptJC_5705846048

Comment: Thanks for the links but the problem is that i already did the xamarin course and I don't have time to do the full C# course. I need made this project to see if xamarin was a good choice for us to create a bigger project, but till now I only got problems with xamarin. I know a lot of programming languages such as php java (android development) etc. but I just cant get anything to work in xamarin. this afternoon i have to show my colleagues what I have learned about xamarin these 2 weeks but now I have only bad stories to tell them. :(

Comment: I don't know if you could help me if i send you the project? @Frauke

Comment: @Kevin I'm at work now, so I don't have time to look at a complete solution, I'm afraid. What I can tell you is that all the problems you mentioned are due to the fact that you don't know enough C# - they have absolutely nothing to do with Xamarin. In all honesty, I think your management messed up by giving you the task of evaluating Xamarin - 2 weeks is not enough time to even learn C#, let alone a complicated platform, to a degree where you can make recommendations. Not your fault, you did amazingly well, it was just a completely unreasonable demand IMHO

Comment: @Kevin Xamarin is a great platform, it can do anything you can do in native development environments, but you need to have real C# expertise. If your company has Java/Swift/Objective-C expertise instead, Xamarin may not be the right way to go, although if you do a lot of apps for mobile platforms, it will save time in the long run to invest in proper C#/Xamarin training for your devs.